# how do I clear the device memory cache

Tags: java, android, android-transitions

In my android app, I am using transition scenes. On the Emulator, it works fine but on a physical device the more times a transition happens, the time between the transition grows, slowing down the app. I need to clear the device cache memory to stop this from happening.

I tried a code to clear the cache memory, but the android studio gives out a warning that the delete code will be ignored. I have not found any other way to do this.

```
public void clearCache() {
Log.i(TAG, "Clearing Cache.");
File[] dir = mContext.getCacheDir().listFiles();
if(dir != null){
    for (File f : dir){
        f.delete();
    }
   }
}
```

The delete() method call is ignored by the system so the code doesn't work. I need to clear the device cache can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

`android studio gives out a warning that the delete code will be ignored` that's wrong, it does not give such warning.

It says that **the result** of `f.delete()` is ignored.
`f.delete()` returns `true` / `false` as the result, which means

- `true` if file has been deleted
- `false` if file deletion failed.

You may ignore this warning, if you don't care about the `delete()` result, or check it like

```
for (File f : dir){
    if(!f.delete()) {
        //deletion failed. Do something about it
    }
}
```

If you just want the warning to disappear, you can do something like

```
for (File f : dir){
    boolean ignored = f.delete();
}
```

Comment: So I misunderstood the warning. I will try it later today and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work the f.delete() call returns a false every time. The documentation says that only if the file is empty will the delete method work otherwise it will be ignored. So I am back to square one because this isn't working.

Comment: @אריאלעדן you have missread again. It says `the directory must be empty in order to be deleted`. File is just fine to be non-empty. if you have subdirectories in your cache dir, then you have to clear them first

Comment: But if the f.delete() returns false, doesn't that mean that the fils are not deleted? the dir != null returned true that means that CachDir was not empty.

Comment: does `dir` have subdirectories? If it has, then they have to be empty to be deleted

Comment: I have check what is in the dir and there is only one reference to a WebView. My app doesn't open a WebView but it has an Intent that  allows the user to open the system browser if they want more information an a subject. I think that is why the f.delete() is ignored. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: that's something totally unrelated to what I ask: Does your cache directore have any subdirectories?

Comment: I didn't see any subdirectories, but maybe I didn't use the right method call. I used the log to print out the contents of the f files names. I didn't see another way.

Comment: you can use `File.isDirectory()` to check if it is a directory, or not

Comment: Yes, you are right the method call showes that I have subdirectories in the cache.  How do I delete them?

Comment: I get two calls to a subdirectory, the first one is simply named WebView and the second: org.chromium.android_webview

Comment: that is exactly why they are not getting deleted - directories have to be empty to be removed. You have to remove all the files inside them first.

Comment: I have noticed in this when using this method that after every deletion of a subDirectory, the next time it forms a subdirectory inside the subDirectory. That is why it is recursive, can't this cause also a slow down in the app?

Comment: I have found another problem running this method. It only works the first time the app is run an a device. After that, it does nothing.